# Is XCode's auto-complete code misleading programmers?

Tags: xcode, autocomplete, grand-central-dispatch

When I type "dispatch_after" in XCode, it auto-completes GCD code as below:

```
int64_t delayInSeconds = 2.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    <#code to be executed on the main queue after delay#>
});
```

let's look this statement :

```
int64_t delayInSeconds = 2.0;
```

int64_t is the synonyms of "long long",but here we assign a double value "2.0" to this kind of variable delayInSeconds.So the fractional part of the value will be discarded.If you assign it with value "0.3",the variable's value will be 0. I think this template of code will mislead programmers and the right code should be `float delayInSeconds = 2.0;`Am I right? thanks in advance.

Comment: Agreed, it's very misleading.

Comment: This seems to be fixed in Xcode, both Xcode 4.6.3 and 5.0.1 create the code `double delayInSeconds = 2.0;`.